# Swap a view's model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript, models

Basically I'm trying to figure out the best way to swap a model and react to that event.

```
class View extends Backbone.View
    initialize: ()->
        #do stuff
    swapModel: (newModel)->
        @model = newModel

view = new View({model:firstModel})

view.swapModel(newModel)
```

Is this all I have to do to swap out a view's model? Are there any other side effects I should plan for? What would be the best way to respond to this swap? Should I trigger a swap event in swapModel?

Thanks!

Comment: I would think you'd need to rebind any events that were being listened for on your model in your view if you have them as well.

Comment: Why not just destroy the old view and create a new one?

Comment: @muistooshort maybe I could, but part of the views job is to react to the creation of the new model. Everything in the dom needs to stay and it does some changes to the dom when the model switches. It seemed easier to me to swap the model if it worked how I thought it might.

Comment: I agree with kinakuta.  Perhaps you should think about writing a method to merge whatever new model you want to the existing and letting the view redraw the dom as needed. "Everything in the dom needs to stay and it does some changes to the dom" - sounds like the dom changes no matter what.  If you were to merge, as in, take the raw attributes of the new desired model, and foo and zam them into a hash and then send that hash to the existing model.save(), you'd be golden i'd think.

Comment: Perhaps your view should be watching a collection then and have sub-views for each model. Or maybe you should have a container view that cares about the model create/destroy events and creates/destroys new views inside it as needed. Views can contain other views.

Comment: @muistooshort Thanks Mu, yea I will likely add another layer of views to handle the dom actions when replacing the view hooked to the model.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Don't swap models in a view. You'll run in to all kinds of problems related to DOM event, Model events in the view, etc. I've tried to do this a dozen times or more, and in every single case, I re-wrote my code so that I would create a new view instance for each model. The code was cleaner, simpler, easier to understand and easier to maintain and work with.

Comment: Thanks Derick, I trust your opinion on all this stuff. This will likely save me lots of time. :)

Answer (score 1):

A very simple example of one way to do it.  Why are you trying to swap models though?

```
MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function() {

     this.myTrigger = {};
    _.extend(this.myTrigger, Backbone.Events);

    this.myTrigger.on("modelChange", function(msg) {
      alert("Triggered " + msg);
    },this);

    },
    swapModel: function(model) {
      // do something with model
      // then trigger listeners
      this.myTrigger.trigger("modelChange", "a model change event");
    }
});

var myview = new MyView()
myview.swapModel()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a collection that only allows one model. This way you don't touch the model and can call render as many times as you want. Something like this:

```
var SpecialCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    swap: function (model) {
        //remove all models
        this.reset();
        //add one model
        this.add(model);
    }
});

var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({
    initialize: function(){
       this.listenTo(this.collection, 'add', this.render);
    },
    render: function() {
        this.model = this.collection.first()
        //do your normal rendering here
    }
});

var c = new SpecialCollection();
var v = new MyView({collection: c});
c.swap({name: 'Sam'});
//view should render
c.swap({name: 'Dave'});
//view should render
```

You could lock down the Collection rules a bit further but I think it serves as a good example to get you going.